# Please change our visited link colours on Meta to something more legible than bright yellow on white

Tags: bug, design, css

Our link colours on Meta RPG are a sort of off-yellow (as opposed to red on main site), and mostly they're pretty legible, but the visited link colour is not, being [a fairly bright yellow (#d29b44) on white.](http://example.com) Text in visited links here is pretty hard to read.

According to [the Web AIM colour contrast checker](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/), it has a pretty bad contrast ratio:

> [image: contrast ratio of 2.47:1]

For good legibility you usually want to shoot for at least 3.5:1 or preferably 4.5:1.

In the sidebar links are upon a background of `#FFF8DC`, which means a contrast ratio of only 2.32:1.

The unvisited link colour isn't quite so bad:

> [image: contrast ratio of 3.93:1]

**Please replace our visited link colour on meta with with a more legible colour.**

If that involves changing the link colours altogether (visited *or* unvisited), I'm fine with that. I'm not attached to the yellow. A couple of weeks ago our links turned blue on here for about half an hour. It wasn't quite the right blue for our site, but it was nevertheless an improvement. You can still see it [`if your link's in code`](http://example.com). Our main site's red would also be fine!

Comment: Can't you use your browser settings to override any site-specific link colours? Don't get me wrong, I see the appeal of changing it. But if most don't see the need, that's always an option.

Comment: @Jason_c_o I don't know how, I'd rather see site specific link colors, and I imagine stack exchange's devs would be interested in resolving this if it is a problem.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Low-contrast text is generally considered a usability bug best fixed once at the source rather than over and over again by those visiting the page who struggle with it.

Comment: Of course. But it offers a good temp. Solution until the issue is resolved. AFAIK it's browser-wide though, not site specific.

Comment: can we ping a dev on this?

Comment: @Tritium21 They have been pinged in a sense by virtue of me creating this question. ([They see per site meta bug reports.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240571/152515))